# Cannot view 'Unarchive' messages back in the inbox in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Yesterday I deleted some messages from Facebook. I want to bring them back to my inbox today. So I logged into my Facebook. Then -

1. I went to messages.
2. Clicked on More -> then Archived.
3. Then I found the deleted messages.
4. I clicked on one and from Action selected Unarchive.
5. Then the selected message disappeared from there and I thought it would be in the inbox. So I went to inbox and looked there.

But the message is not found.

Why is it so?

---

So I decided to test Facebook and as the part of it, I just archived a message and tried to unarchive it. No problem occurred this time. The message successfully returned to the inbox.

Now my question is what happened to the previously unarchived message?

Can I get it back still?